# How to update MYSQL table's clolum's specific part

Tags: mysql, database

MYSQL table have 2 columns.

```
id      image path

1255    /images/abc/1255.png
1256    /images/pqr/1256.png
1257    /images/rsrrrr/1255.png
1258    /images/fg&rrdr/1257.png
1259    /images/v/1255.png
1260    /images/r/1258.png
```

I want to update image path like this:

```
id      image path

1255    /images/abc/1255.png
1256    /images/pqr/1256.png
1257    /images/rsrrrr/1257.png
1258    /images/fg&rrdr/1258.png
1259    /images/v/1259.png
1260    /images/r/1260.png
```

Meaning characters after last / should be the "id".png

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: First get the path and the id and then update the path with adding the id in the path

Comment: I think this is difficult to do with a single statement. You'd need a REPLACE() with a regex, which I don't believe is supported by MySQL. Check this out for a possible answer using a third party library: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50210/regex-with-update-query-my-sql

Comment: Use a replace and as string to replace, isolate the number with the delimiters being the dot and the last forward slash.

Comment: Code added ! Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00e89/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `image path` varchar(24))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `image path`)
VALUES
    (1255, '/images/abc/1255.png'),
    (1256, '/images/pqr/1256.png'),
    (1257, '/images/rsrrrr/1255.png'),
    (1258, '/images/fg&rrdr/1257.png'),
    (1259, '/images/v/1255.png'),
    (1260, '/images/r/1258.png')
;

update table1 
set `image path` = replace(`image path`, 
                           SUBSTRING_INDEX(`image path`, '/', -1),
                           concat(id, '.png')
                          )
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00e89/1/0)**:

```
|   id |               image path |
|------|--------------------------|
| 1255 |     /images/abc/1255.png |
| 1256 |     /images/pqr/1256.png |
| 1257 |  /images/rsrrrr/1257.png |
| 1258 | /images/fg&rrdr/1258.png |
| 1259 |       /images/v/1259.png |
| 1260 |       /images/r/1260.png |
```

Answer (score 4):

This one should work with any depth:

```
update tblName 
set image_path = concat(replace(image_path, SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_path, '/', -1), '') , id, '.png')
```

Comment: What if image other than png gets uploaded such as gif, jpeg , bmp ?? You cant restrict file format. You should Retain old image format instead of hardcoding to png..

Comment: 'Meaning characters after last / should be the "id".png' has been specified by topic starter

Answer (score 1):

If your folder level is having Depth 2 exactly, Then use **Working code** I tested:

```
update tblName set image_path =
concat( 
SUBSTRING_INDEX((image_path),'/',1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX((image_path),'/',3),
'/',id, 
'.',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_path, '/', -1), '.', -1)  /*last path*/
)
```